# How to call an asynctask inside a button click event

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am writing this application where I get live images from a tcp connection and I need to display them on an ImageViev.

What I am doing is calling the asynctask inside the button click. but it seem to create a number of background threads.

this is the code for the button click event

```
    btnLive.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try
        {
            String name = ((Button)v).getText().toString();
            if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("Live"))
            {
                DataOutputStream dos;
                DataInputStream dis;
                String reply;

                if(config.conn.isConnected())
                {
                    dos = new DataOutputStream(config.conn.getOutputStream());
                    dos.writeBytes("STREAM-LIVE-IMAGES");                                       
                    dos.flush();
                    //dis = new DataInputStream(in);

                    in = config.conn.getInputStream();                      
                    while (true) 
                    {                               
                        new myTask().execute(in);
                    }
                }                   
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Log.d("Live Button ", "Exception " + ex.getMessage() );
        }
    }
});
```

and this the code for the asyncTask

```
 class myTask extends AsyncTask<InputStream, Integer, Bitmap> {

protected Bitmap doInBackground(InputStream...in) 
{
    Bitmap bmp = null;

    try 
    {
        //Do some none UI stuff here and return a value *result                 
        byte[] rcvPacket = ReadJpegBinaryAndRemoveDelimiter(in[0]);
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(rcvPacket, 0, rcvPacket.length);
        Log.d("Live Image Streaming ", "Recieved Images: " + rcvPacket.length + " " +  bmp);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();                    
    }
    return bmp;
}
```

Comment: You can't execute as many AsyncTasks as you wish. There is limit for that.

Comment: I guess it's better here to implement a Service for uploading. Run this Service and pass there your bitmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to sort it out with a background thread because asynctask wasnt the right option for my issue.

So I created a separate background thread and used a post runnable method on the imageview to update the UI.

Answer (score 4):

```
while (true) {                               
 new myTask().execute(in);
}
```

because you are executing `AsyncTask` in loop, in your case in *infinite loop*, it's not sounds very well, you need to change it.

You need to *execute* in outside of loop. You shouldn't, musn't do it.

Just call

```
new myTask().execute(in);
```

without loop.

Comment: so will the asynctask run on its own because I need to keep streaming images untill I wanna stop the streaming? Thanks for the prompt reply

Comment: simply don't execute it in loop. every time you click on button just execute asynctask and let it do its work.

Comment: So that wont get me the live images continuously then? what I need is like when i press the live button it should continuosly stream the images. Your solution will get me only one image with every button click I guess

Comment: you should do it in doInBackground method. just execute AsyncTask once and get all images in doInBackground.

Comment: If you have seen my code I am doing it in the doInBackground method.

Comment: what about when you first pass all images to some List<InputStream> and it pass to AsyncTask and in doInBackground create loop.

Comment: @deciever if you have read my code I am using a TCP connection here to get the images. I am using an inputStream to recieve a bytearray of images and then display them in an imageview. You have been decieved by my code lol

Comment: so why you don't do it in doInBackground? when you click on the button,just execute task and all work you need do in doInBackground also getting InputStream from Connection.